# Convert Maya 2013 to X3D file

Tags: maya, x3d

Is there any way to convert a file from Maya 2013 to an X3D file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you specifically need X3D? Seems like the only project that did this for maya is something like 5+ years old.

If you are looking for a [pretty widely supported XML-based format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COLLADA#Software_tools), COLLADA appears to be very accepted. There is a plugin for Maya called [ColladaMaya](http://colladamaya.sourceforge.net/)

Here is a list of conversion tools that claim to handle COLLADA -> X3D:
http://www.web3d.org/x3d/content/examples/X3dResources.html

Answer (score 0):

you can try http://www.inka3d.com if you can go with webgl instead of x3d